# Archivos de certificaciones en contendor docker

Tags: python, docker, ssl, certificado-ssl, docker-compose

Estoy trabajando en un contenedor docker, ya lo logramos poner en producción con un dominio. (midominio.com)

El proyecto es una web en python con django.

Se generaron los archivos de certificación .cert y .key, pero al momento de realizar la configuración para apache y levantar el sitio con la certificación, nuestro contenedor no corre y no lanza ningún error.

Alguno de ustedes me podría orientar por favor. Mis configuración es la siguiente:

Archivo dockerfile

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils nano curl cron apache2 apache2-utils libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 gettext python3-pysocks
RUN ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN ln /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ADD ./webapp.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN mkdir /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp
ADD ./requirements.txt /webapp/ 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /webapp/
```

Archivo docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    #command: ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND" ]
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/webapp
  - ./ssl:/etc/ssl/certs/webapp
  - ./crontab.sh:/etc/crontab.sh
environment:
  PYTHONPATH: /var/www/webapp:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
  - "3306:3306"
command: ["sh", "/etc/crontab.sh" ]
```

Archivo config (Apache)

```
# Insecure site
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName midominio.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/webapp/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/webapp>
         <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
         </Files>
    </Directory>
    Alias /static/ /var/www/webapp/webapp/static/

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R,L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


#Secure site
<VirtualHost *:443> 
    ServerName midominio.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/webapp/wsgi.py

    SSLEngine on
    <Directory /var/www/webapp>
             <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
         </Files>
    </Directory>
    Alias /static/ /var/www/webapp/webapp/static/


    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/webapp/midominio.com.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/webapp/midominio.com.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Pareciera que en el dockerfile les falta el COPY de los certificados: `COPY ./path/to/ssl.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt` y `COPY ./path/to/ssl.key /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key`

Comment: Los certificados lo paso desde mi docker-compose, en volumenes

Comment: Y un `docker logs web` no te muestra pistas de posibles errores?